# Load obj file with Three.js in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, three.js

We have to load an obj file with Three.js in Cordova. We have this code:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas : document.getElementById('scene'),
    antialias : true
});
renderer.setSize(ww,wh);
renderer.shadowMap = true;
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50,ww/wh, 0.1, 10000 );
camera.position.set(20,40,60);
scene.add(camera);
projector = new THREE.Projector();

var ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
ambLight.instensity = 1;
scene.add( ambLight );

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.minDistance = 50;
controls.maxDistance = 150;

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load(fileURL, function(object) {
    model = object;
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
            child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            child.geometry.center();
        }
    });
    scene.add(model);
});
```

This code runs well on the browser, because we used for another thing. But now we are running it on a Cordova app.

And the logs we are getting are:

```
"THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float extension not supported."
"THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float_linear extension not supported."
"THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_half_float extension not supported."
"THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_half_float_linear extension not supported."
"THREE.WebGLRenderer: ANGLE_instanced_arrays extension not supported."
"THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_element_index_uint extension not supported."
"THREE.FileLoader: HTTP Status 0 received."
"OBJLoader: 2854.889ms"
```

We are running the app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab E, Android 4.4.4.
We already installed `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` plugin, because I read over there that with this plugin we can execute WebGL on old versions of Android, but we still see a black screen. But if I put some log to see if enter in the function, the log is showed.

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

### EDIT

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you able to use the device to open any of the examples from here: https://threejs.org/examples/ ? These examples are also available in the three.js package. You could try porting one into a blank Cordova app to see if it will run there, too.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. We have tried with other simple examples from internet and they don't show neither.

Comment: The [Crosswalk FAQ](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Canvas-and-WebGL-support) has info about enabling WebGL on devices for which it's been blacklisted. Maybe that will help?

Comment: Thank you, but I just tried what they say about this and still doesn't work.